Converting the raw DN (Digital Number) into physical unit
This code on this article is on sorting of the array (and reducing). My query is regarding the addition of 149.0 to the thermal bands in order to execute the scaling factor.
The particular code snippet:
  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);

Of course, the reason for choosing 149.0 specifically would be based on the calibration coefficients provided by a scientific research to accurately reflect the relationship between the raw sensor readings and the physical properties they represent but why 149? The MTL documentation's RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10/11 does not exhibit the digit 149 but the usual 0.1. Even the  RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10/11 value was taken as 0.00341802 instead of 0.000341.
Could I get any links to any paper stating and calculating the reason behind altering the documentation values such as 149 and 0.0003?
